# Android check if native activity has started

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-instrumentation

I am trying to test if my application has correctly started Android Dialer app.

Based on what I have found about unit testing and instrumentation, I have created this test:

```
public void testPerformOperation() throws Exception {
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor("com.android.phone.Dialer", null, true);
    operationPerformer.performOperation("tel:111222333");
    Activity activity = monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(5000);
    assertNotNull(activity);
}
```

But this always returns AssertionFailedError.

I have also tried to do set first parameter of `addMonitor()` to `IntentFilter.create(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls")`, but this gave me the same error. Also I have been searching for other MimeTypes to use, but haven't found any (looks like dialer uses no MimeType).

How should I check if dialer has started?

Answer (score 0):

check if your activity is running

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo act: manager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (MyActivity.class.getName().equals(
                    act.service.getClassName())) {

                //do
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't have or can't find proper activity name for native Dialer App.